# How do I filter out null values in my Promise.all result?

Tags: javascript, promise

```
exports.getMentionedUsers = function(str) {
    return Promise.all(getUsernamesFromString(str).map(username => {
        return db.ref('/users').orderByChild('username').equalTo(username).once('value').then(snapshot => {
            return snapshot.val();
        });
    }));
}
```

Right now, if snapshot.val() is null, the element is still included in the final result.

How do I *not* insert a null element in the final map?

Comment: if(snapshot.val()) return snapshot.val()

Comment: Use Array filter function and filter the null elements from your array

Comment: `.then(arr => arr.filter(Boolean))`?

Answer (score 8):

Add `then` callback and use `Array#filter` to remove `null` elements:

```
exports.getMentionedUsers = function(str) {
    return Promise
        .all(getUsernamesFromString(str).map(username => {
            return db.ref('/users').orderByChild('username').equalTo(username).once('value').then(snapshot => {
              return snapshot.val();
            });
        }))
        .then(values => values.filter(v => v);
}
```

**Update:** If you need to delete elements *exactly* with `null` value, you should use this filter: `v => v !== null`.

Comment: I would recommend something more canonical like `.then(values => values.filter(Boolean))` but this effectively does the same thing.

Comment: This does not specifically test for `null`.  It removes any falsey value, including non-null values like `0` or `""`.  Since the OP asked specifically for `null`, perhaps you should explicitly test for `null` before removing `values.filter(v => v !== null);`

Comment: `v => v`  is most important piece of code